# Is it possible to rename a GCP Cloud Run Service?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

Is there a way to change a service via the Console or an API? It seems this is not possible at least from the console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing/adjusting the Service Name on Cloud Run is not supported. As explained on [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/deploying#service) :

> Service names must be unique per region and project or per cluster. A
>   service name cannot be changed later and is publicly visible when
>   using Cloud Run (fully managed).

You cannot change it via Cloud Console neither Cloud SDK.

Answer (score 9):

JC98 is right, you can't rename your service. BUT there is a new feature. In the list of the services, you can copy an existing one

[image]

Thus, select the the old service, copy it into a new one with the new name, and then delete the old one.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if i understand your question correctly but There are several ways to set a service's name in App Engine. If you use Java with Maven for example, depends on your programming language you are using

Java with Maven for example (in the appengine-web.xml file)

```
set <module>service_name</module>
```

Python (app.yaml)

```
set service: service_name
```

Comment: Question is about Cloud Run, not App engine.

Comment: @VilleRinne that's why i mentioned at the 1st line "I don't know if i understand your question correctly"